# Working with a while-loop, how to make so it does not keep making copys/adding the same items over and over?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The goal is for the while-loop to search for new users (items) all the time and once it has found someone it gets added into the list and my stacklayout. I get all of the rows in DB just fine, the problem is that the items it finds gets added but then it keeps getting readded so i get multiple Buttons with the same values. The query is always returning all rows so it has something to do with that but I am not sure how to work around it when something is already added.

Right now with my current code it correctly adds the ones each 3000 milisec it founds but the current problem that I have is that it keeps adding them again and again even if they have been there before. 
I need to prevent that and only make so it adds an item one time. This is my code:

To show you guys an example how it looks right now:

ID 1, ID 2....

after 3000 milisec...

ID 1, ID 2.... 
and it keeps adding the same values that has alrdy been posted.

```
public List<Tuple<string>> applicantList = new List<Tuple<string>> ();

async void loadActiveAnimation () 
    {
        while (true) {

            await Task.Delay (3000);

            var seeHowMany = await phpApi.getInfo ();

            if ((seeHowMany ["results"] as JArray).Count > 0) {

                foreach (var items in seeHowMany ["results"]) {

                    applicantList.Add (
                        Tuple.Create(
                            items ["id"].ToString ()
                        )
                    );

                    foreach (var values in applicantList) {

                        var button = new Button ();
                        button.Text = values.Item1;
                        myStackLayout.Children.Add (button);

                    }

                }

            } 

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not missing the obvious:

after:

```
var seeHowMany = await phpApi.getInfo ();
```

Clear the applicantList List (`applicantList.Clear();`)

If you want the buttons to reset too, then clear `myStackLayout.Children`.

This basically would check the database (or whatever) every 3 seconds, get the list of applicants, clear the current list, fill the list, clear the buttons, create the buttons from the current list of applicants, then do the same again after 3 seconds...

Comment: It works. I had put the foreach loop inside the alrdy existing loop which made things a bit weird. now it works though. Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why the above answer that you stated worked for the question you asked, and was marked as correct, was later marked as not correct?

Comment: It worked ok when I had a few rows in the db, but once i added more items into the db it took way to long before the labels (in my case) appeared after being cleared.

Comment: Sorry, but given the issue you raised and the code you supplied, the answer was correct. If you have changed the boundaries of what is required, then you should ask another question. I think that your query is the issue - if you are retrieving all records every time, then that is the wrong approach. You would most likely want to retrieve only the newest ones and then only add them to your list.

Comment: Ok, yeah I will probably make a new post regarding this then. I will give you the answer

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look at your new question and see if I can help with the solution...

Comment: I am not quite sure how I should ask the question because it is a mix between frontend code (c#) and php backend right to make it work well. Any suggestions as a "title" to the question?

Comment: It may just be a design problem now. If you only want to load the latest changes/additions, then track that in the database calling code and only get the data you want to add to the list. You probably don't want to load all data on registrations from the database and send it to the browser to sort out each time. Have a time stamp check or similar, and only retrieve new records to send back. You could also remove old entries from your list based on total number or how old they are. Without knowing the requirements I can only give you ideas to go with. Good luck tho.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach (var items in searchApplicants ["results"]) {
    theId = items ["applicantId"].ToString ();
    // loadProfiles should be here to load the current ID before changing.
}

loadProfiles ();
```

Your loop assigns all the value returned by `searchApplicants[]` in turn to **theId** and then invokes `loadProfiles()` so only the last one gets processed.

I would also reduce the scope of **theId** and make it a local variable to pass to `loadProfiles()` which would have made the problem clearer.

If the implementation `searchApplicants[]` returns you a different collection every time then you shouldn't have any duplicate.

Comment: it keeps adding the same items over and over when I put the loadProfiles inside there as well. (I have two items that it finds in the list) that keeps getting added over and over. also it laggs a bit with my current code. it is not running "smoothly".

searchApplicants holds a list of users ID that has signed up for a certain thing. so it keeps running through all of the list right now and keep adding them even if they have been added before

Comment: If you moved the loadProfiles inside and it still adds the same values, the problem is likely to be in searchApplicants then. Where is it coming from? Did you implement it?

Comment: Maybe I explained a bit badly but all of the different items with their ids gets added (so i can with ease get their names + photos). So I recieve the different rows in the database just fine, but the problem is that it keeps getting readded every 3000 milisec. so for example it finds the name joe and Anna. and the thing is that it keeps getting readded into my stacklayout + scrollview, so joe + anna keeps getting added every 3000 sec so I get multiple of them

Comment: Your code is a bit generic, I can't see any database access or any source for the ids, we can't help you without some other details. I'm just making assumptions and guessing getTheID is affecting the values of searchApplicants.

Comment: I believe I understand your issue now. Your code that returns data from the DB always returns all rows no matter what. You could fix it somehow by only finding "new" rows. Or, you can remember in code which rows you've already gotten and only add those that are new. Does this sound like the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: yes that is the exact problem. just like you said it: the query is always returning all the rows

Comment: Now it's completely different, the foreach around applicationList should be out of the external loop; otherwise you end up adding them every time plus the new ones: E.G. 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: @medvedo by the way: why are you using a Tuple for one string?

Comment: I am going to get/add multiple items later on so i am working with that right now otherwise i would use a dictionary of course

Comment: If the database returns the same rows every time, a quick hack would be to replace the List<string> with an HashSet<string> which doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Tried it out, same result it seems like, i use this code instead `public HashSet <Tuple<string>> applicantList = new HashSet<Tuple<string>> ();`

Comment: I was assuming it was one string, if you use a HashSet<Tuple< the instances will be different. If you move the applicationList loop out you shouldn't get duplication for the first set.

Comment: Then if you don't want duplicates at the next while iteration, either you Clear() the List<> or you keep another collection of the already added one and check before creating a new button. (This is more pair programming than a Q&A...)

Comment: Yea but I do not want to clear the list. I want the ones who got added to remain there and then when the loop searches and finds a new one that one adds as well.
I have got a bigger understanding of the solution now though which is good but not 100 % sure how to execute it. Appreciate the pointers and all the help

Comment: Then you can modify the query to return only new items or do a duplicate check as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
async void loadProfiles ()
{
    var getTheInfo = await phpApi.getProfileFromID (theId); //i gather the rest of the info connected with the correct ID.

    // store only newly added images this cycle
    List<Tuple<string, string>> newImages = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    foreach (var item in getTheInfo["results"]) /i loop the correct info out from the ID
    {
        // append to newImages instead of imagesList
        newImages.Add (
            Tuple.Create(
                item ["Photo"].ToString (),
                item ["Name"].ToString ()
            )
        );

    }

    // loop through newImages instead of imagesList
    foreach (var img in newImages ) {

        var inner = new StackLayout ();
        var image = new CircleImage ();

        image.Source = img.Item1;

        var button = new Button ();
        button.Text = img.Item2;
        inner.Children.Add (image);
        inner.Children.Add (button);
        myStackLayout.Children.Add (inner);

    }

    // add newImages to imagesList
    imagesList.AddRange(newImages);
}
```

Comment: same outcome with this solution unfortantly

Comment: Okay, I see. Your query is always returning all rows. I assumed for some reason that the value of getTheInfo only contained new data.

Comment: Yes exactly, it returns all of the rows all the time.

Comment: In that case, a combination of the solution I gave above, and the ability to edit your query to only return newly added records would solve it. Alternatively, you can track it in memory and in code only add what you haven't seen. I hesitate to offer a concrete solution because the "best" way really depends. Quick example, make it so you can pass the DB call a filter such as "...where id > lastSeenId" and save in code the max id after each query (int lastSeenId = newImages.Select(e => e.Id).Max();"

Comment: So there is no way you could do a "full"  frontend solution with a query that returns all rows?

Comment: Been trying to do a solution with your tips above but i have not made alot of progress unfortantly.The answer is still up for grabs. I could do a simple solution with one of the answers refreshing the list but it is not a good solution unfortantly.